# Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found in includes\modules\ultimate_seo_urls5\cache_system\sqlite.php on line 99

Tags: oscommerce

in oscommerce we used ULTIMATE Seo Urls 5 Plugin , in this we are facing a issue like When we go to 
**admin->
Configuration->Seo url5->select your chosen cache system we changed mysql to sqlite**  when changed home page client site shows Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found in **includes\modules\ultimate_seo_urls5\cache_system\sqlite.php** on line 99

at this line i found

```
 protected static function createDatabase() {
      if ( !is_readable( self::$sqlite_db_file ) ) {
        self::$db = new SQLiteDatabase( self::$sqlite_db_file, 0666, $error )
        or trigger_error( 'Failed: ' . $error, E_USER_WARNING );
        self::createTables();
      } else {
        self::$db = new SQLiteDatabase( self::$sqlite_db_file, 0666, $error )
        or trigger_error( 'Failed: ' . $error, E_USER_WARNING );
      }
}
```

this how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

In file 
includes\modules\ultimate_seo_urls5\cache_system\sqlite.php, 
at line 99 **Use**

```
self::$db = new SQLite3( self::$sqlite_db_file, 0666, $error );
```

For both lines for php 5.4 and above
In file
includes/modules/ultimate_seo_urls5/main/usu5.php
at line no 308 use **fetchArray**() rather fetch() function.

```
 $row = $result->fetchArray();
```

I have faced the same problem and corrected it by this way. oscommerce version 2.3